# StackLinks, a URL to Markdown bookmarklet

Tags: script, bookmarklet

In aggregating references, this is useful for wrapping a URL and the content of the `<title>` tag into Markdown:

```
javascript:void(function so_link(){window.prompt('',String().concat("* [",document.title,"]","(",location.href,")") )}() )
```

Comment: Looks useful for mobile especially. List markup not as necessary though.